# core dumped using lock in openMP

Tags: parallel-processing, locking, openmp

I want to parallelize function S and lock every node but I keep getting core dump. I'm trying to use a lock in every node of the graph. It will work if I use a single lock on my nodes.

```
for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
omp_init_lock(&(lock[l]));

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(16)default(none)  private(v)shared(n,Xof,lock)

for(v = 0; v < n; v++) {
    omp_set_lock(&(lock[v]));
    if(Xof[v] == NYC) 
    {
        S(v);   
        }
    omp_unset_lock(&(lock[v]));
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring lock?

Is there perhaps someplace else you are accessing shared state that could cause a data race?

Comment: omp_lock_t lock[n];
  
 for (l = 0; l < n; l++)
 omp_init_lock(&lock[l]);

Comment: the problem is that when I use a single lock I dont get any core dump

Comment: Your code makes no sense to me. Two distinct threads could never get the same value of `v` due to the way parallel loops are distributed, therefore your locks are only being used by a single thread each, which results in absolutely no inter-thread synchronisation (unless `lock[]` is also referred inside `S()`).

Comment: yes but what I want to do here is to lock the whole if statement which includes S().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the most likely cause is that there is a data race (perhaps with some embedded state) within S.

A way to test this would be use n locks but only one thread. If this does not cause a core dump, then S most likely has a data race.

If it does cause a core dump, then your initial hypothesis that is due to the locks might be true. From the code visible, I don't see anything clearly wrong. I might delete the shared clause since it is redundant, but I don't expect that to have an impact.

Comment: Thank you, /i tried it with one thread and it worked. there should be a data race in S()